# WPF and WCF RIA Service+EF or alternatives

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm

Is there any way to get full support for RIA Services+EF for WPF application. I've read previous threads but looks like solution's offered there lacks's essential functionalty like transparent CRUD and Validation API support.

Or is there alternative solutions with other popular communication frameworks/ORM that supports that functionality (to summarize - transparent work with POCO classes in 3-tier enviromnent).

Comment: WPF, WCF, RIA Services are way too complicated to do simpler tasks. I think it's time you check out asp.net mvc with new API controller which is simple JSON end point, easy to configure, can easily sit on shared hosting without complicated setup. We left WPF as metro won't support, and we accepted HTML+JS as uniform UI, with various JavaScript frameworks. It's easier to create JavaScript bridge to access native API, just like phone gap does and these libraries let you keep your static HTML be in your app, and only connect server for data.

Comment: Task's we have are not simple, application already rather big and complicated, we are simply researching possibility to add .NET layer to speed up development of some functions. And btw after doing some plumbing don't see anything too complicated with WPF or WCF OData, developing full-fledged UI with HTML IMHO will requires much more efforts in long run.

Comment: Long run? We moved out of wpf and wcf, to simplify and to make apps accessible and run over all devices, 50% of Internet users won't and can't run wpf, no tablets, including microsoft's own win 8 arm won't run wpf, neither wcf will be supported. Anyway, you and your team is best to judge your needs, i am outlining what problems we had and what we had to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try looking at **[WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx).**

Essentially what this does is abstract EntityFramework's `DataContext` over a WCF service using the OData REST API.  Visual Studio generates all of the necessary plumbing for you so that on your client-side you can access your data tier remotely using the same LINQ queries that you would use when accessing the data source directly.

Comment: What about data modifications? As far as I've understood - WCF RIA takes care not only about transparent accessing data, but also about transparent data modifications too, and with data services you have to do a plumbing for modification yourself?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure OData supports all CRUD operations, not just read access.  With WCF Data Services, you would just be calling `context.SaveChanges()` the same way you would using EF directly.

Comment: Yes, transparent CRUD indeed works. Found good article that asnwers leftover questions (how to work with CodeFirst and Validation API work) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580732.aspx. So I'll wait couple of days to see if there would be alternatives and assign bounty, thanks.